# Swing JScrollPane resets scroll position when updating

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a JPanel view inside a JScrollPane. The Jpanel paints some shapes which has to change dynamically in order to reflect  a changing datamodel.

I have implemented a timer that should repaint the JPanel/JScrollPane which works fine unless that it resets the scroller. The scroller has to remain at its position (where the user has scrolled to).

I have tried to repaint the JPanel, the JScrollPane, the viewport of the JScrollPane etc, but noting seem to solve this problem.

Do you have a hint? The code is quite large so it is hard to isolate an example.

Comment: *"Do you have a hint?"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"The code is quite large so it is hard to isolate an example."*  That's why they pay us the 'big bucks'.

Answer (score 1):

On the swing timer do not much concerning the GUI, just `scrollPane.repaint(50L);`. Especially refrain where not needed from layouting calls: (in)validate.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you are writing. I tried scrollPane.repaint(50L) but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have now isolated the code only to find out that it works isolated. It seem to be related to the context (a very complex form) that it is put in. Now a SSCCE is completely impossible, but any input is still appreciated.